# My docker filesystem duplicates itself for no reason

Tags: docker, docker-compose, debian, debian-buster

My FS has been filled by my docker container (docker pull dependencytrack/apiserver). It seems it has duplicated itself in many subfolders.

```
find /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ -name alpine-1.10.2.jar | wc -l
1550
```

(answer should be closer to 1, I guess).

They all reside in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/[diff|merged]/<random_number1>/tmp/jetty-0_0_0_0-8080-dependency-track-apiserver_jar-dtrack-api-any-<random_number2>/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/`

where `random_number1` is fixed and `random_number2` has many differents values.

Is this problem related to my image, or is it docker ? I don't really know how to proceed from here.

Comment: The second random number is going to be from your application. The diff and merged are two views of the same filesystem, so you should be able to divide that count in half.

Comment: OK thanks for this explanation. Though the number is still way to high, I just included one file in my example, but all files from the application suffer this. Is it application specific ?

Comment: The name on that directory may be from something like `mktemp` which takes a prefix and gives a unique directory, so something in the app may be calling that. I know nothing of that app, so can't help any more than that.